# Importing 2.25 million entries into MYSQL... PHP foreach loop, or MYSQL file import? How should I do it?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Basically I have a list of serial numbers, all 10 digits long. I have a table already set up with 1.3 million records in it. I need these imported, but if it's a duplicate, don't import it. What's the best way to do this.

I have the serial numbers both as a single large file, and separated into 20 smaller files.

PHP and MYSQL are the languages I'm using.

Comment: Can you use something like PhpMyAdmin and write an SQL query? No need to get PHP involved

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html ?

Comment: I didn't know how long the string could be for phpmyadmin... 2.3 million rows long?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use [LOAD DATA INFILE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html). It is by far the fastest way to do it. You can use IGNORE as RMK suggests.

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'filename' IGNORE INTO TABLE tbl_name
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using INSERT_IGNORE in your query:

```
INSERT IGNORE 
INTO exampletable ( column1, column2 )
VALUES( value1, value2 );
```

This way it will ignore the row on duplicate keys.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert.html